# Azure Automation for configuring VM using backup of existing VM restored in Azure storage

Tags: azure, backup, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I need help for Automating the VM configuration using backup of existing VM restored in Azure storage.

Scenario here is- we are be backing up set of VMs
 (using Azure Back Up) using PowerShell and restoring on cloud service with
 reserved IP(We cannot restore VM backup to cloud service with reserved IP using the portal). We want to automate this using Azure Automation.

Thanks,
Manmohan Singh

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what it is you are asking for? (and in its current state this question will probably be closed because of that) Can you share what you have tried so far? what problems you had? what did / didn't work?

Comment: Are you using Azure backup vault and backup agent for this? Your existing VMs are in classic mode or Resource Manager mode?

Comment: We have configured all the VM's in Azure classic portal and taking VM level backup using Azure backup services.                                                We are trying to restore VM's to the existing cloud service ( With reserved IP). currently we are doing this by first restoring the VM's to storage account and then creating new VM using the VHD. we are using this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-automation/                                                                Now we are finding a way to do it using Azure Automation

Comment: You are far more likely to find someone to help you figure your problem out if you can show that you have put some work into it yourself. Show some code you've tried, what has / hasn't worked. That way people are more likely to help because it will feel less like they're doing your homework for you.